# Solving algebraic looping problem by introducing a unit delay

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, control-systems

First, here is my code.

```
(*Parameters*)

tend = 100;
Mu = 1;
Rho = 2.62*10^-12 Exp[-(500000 - r[t] )/64500];
Rtet = Rearth + 500000 - r[t] ;
ugc = 6.67*10^11; 
massEarth = 5.9721986*10^24; 
v = Sqrt[(ugc*massEarth)/Rtet]
c1 = 2.67;
a1 = 8;
m1 = 1000;

c2 = 2.5;
a2 = 4;
m2 = 500;

B1 = c1*a1/m1;
B2 = c2*a2/m2;

hh = 64500;
dt = 0.005;

k1 = 1;
k2 = 1;

(*Disturbance*)

Q1 = 
  v^2*r[t]*Rho*Cos[Theta]Cos[Phi]*((Mu*(B1-B2)/2) -   
    (dt*hh)*(1-Cos^2[Phi[t]]Sin^2[Theta[t]])^0.5/Cos[Theta[t]]Cos[Phi[t]]);

Q2 = 
  v^2*r[t]*Rho*Sin[Theta]Sin[Phi]*((Mu*(B2-B1)/2) -   
    (dt*hh)*(1-Cos^2[Phi[t]]Sin^2[Theta[t]])^0.5/Cos[Theta[t]]Cos[Phi[t]]);

(*Flip Flop Control Law*)

 u1 = k1*Theta'[t]-(Q2+u2)*(Theta'[t]+1)/Phi'[t];

 u2 = k2*Phi'[t]-(Q1+u1)*Phi'[t]/(Theta'[t]+1);

(*Anti Disturbance Control Law*)

sigma = (u1+Q1/(2*Theta'[t]+1))+(u2+Q2/(2*Phi'[t]));

(*System Dynamics*)

e1 = Theta''[t]+(Theta'[t]+1)*(2*sigma-       
2*Phi'[t]*Tan[Phi[t]])+3*Sin[Theta[t]]*Cos[Theta[t]]-Q1;

e2 = Phi''[t]+2*sigma*Phi'[t]+
((Theta'[t]+1)^2+3*Cos^2[Theta[t]])*Sin[Phi[t]]*Cos[Phi[t]]-Q2;

e3 = r'[t]-sigma*r[t];

(*Initial conditions*)

system = 
  NDSolve[{
   e1 == 0, e2 == 0, e3 == 0, Theta[0] == 0.1, 
   Theta'[0] == 0, Phi[0] == 0.1, Phi'[0] == 0.001, r[0] == 1}, 
   {Theta, Phi, r}, {t, 0, tend}, MaxSteps -> Infinity];

(*Plot*)

Plot[Evaluate[Theta[t] /.system], {t,0,tend}, 
  Frame -> True, ImageSize ->  {400, 300}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[12], FrameLabel ->  {"time(s)", "Theta (rad)"}, 
  PlotRange -> All]

Plot[Evaluate[Phi[t] /.system], {t,0,tend}, 
  Frame -> True, ImageSize ->  {400, 300}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[12], FrameLabel -> {"time(s)", "Phi (rad)"}, 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

The problem here lies in the `(*Flip Flop Control Law *)` section. Since the equation in `u1` is dependent on `u2` and vice-versa, these two equations result in an algebraic loop. One method I know of for overcomming this problem is to introduce a unit delay. In SIMULINK, the "Unit Delay" block is available, but in *Mathematica*, how do I program a unit delay for this system so I can simulate and plot the results successfully for both Theta and Phi?

Comment: A minimal example designed to be easy to understand instead of your full blown code could be much better

Comment: Do you have `System Modeler`? If so, `TransportDelay` will accomplish this, and you probably can replace the whole chunk with one of the flip-flop components that incorporates TD as a sub-component.

Comment: That's the problem, I don't have a System Modeler. No possible ways to solve this without relying on System Modeler per se ?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be first solve for $u1$ and $u2$ from the flip-flop control law. However that turns out to have no solutions, indicating some problem with the control law?

```
Solve[{u1 == k1*Theta'[t] - (Q2 + u2)*(Theta'[t] + 1)/Phi'[t], 
u2 == k2*Phi'[t] - (Q1 + u1)*Phi'[t]/(Theta'[t] + 1)}, {u1, u2}]
```

> {}

I looked into it a bit more and saw that the $Phi'[t]$ term is a potential issue.

```
Solve[{u1 == k1*Theta'[t] - (Q2 + u2) (Theta'[t] + 1)/foo, 
u2 == k2*Phi'[t] - (Q1 + u1)*Phi'[t]/(Theta'[t] + 1)}, {u1, u2}];
Denominator[{u1, u2} /. %]
```

> {{foo - Phi'[t], (-foo + Phi'[t]) (1 + Theta'[t])}}

Are you sure that the expressions in your code are correct?

Comment: Hi Suba, first of all thank you so much in trying to solve this problem. Here's the thing, it is an algebraic loop, therefore it is bound to have no solutions. The expressions are correct, but I figured out one way to solve the control law, which is by just introducing an initial value for u2 so that u1 can be calculated and be used in the following u2 equation. Now, I have no idea how to insert an initial value for u2 in the u1 equation. Do you know how to do that here in Mathematica ? That would definitely solve the control law problem. Thanks a lot and looking for your reply.

Comment: Aaron, this is a paraphrase from p.262 of the book 'Continuous System Simulation' by Cellier and Kofman: "How can we deal with the algebraic loop? ... we can solve for the unknowns...". The algebraic loop you have should have a solution for u1 and u2. Otherwise it makes no sense. "I have no idea how to insert an initial value for u2 in the u1 equation." There is no 'u1 equation' (or 'u2 equation'), because you cannot solve for u1 (or u2). You are stuck with an unsolvable algebraic loop involving both u1 and u2.